# Looking for a hypergeometric 2F1 identity

Tags: hypergeometric-function

I'm trying to express
$$_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2} , 1;\,\frac{3}{2}+m;\,z\right), \quad m\in\mathbb{Z}\quad\text{and}\quad m\geq0$$
in terms of $\tanh^{-1}(\sqrt{z})$ and $\sqrt{z}$, basically generalizing [these](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/07/07/02/) results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Maple, I am getting
$$
{}_2F_1\left(\frac12,1;\frac32+m;z\right) = A_m(z)\operatorname{atanh}\sqrt{z}+B_m(z)
$$
where
$$
A_m(z) = \frac{2(z-1)^m\Gamma(m+\frac32)}{z^{m+1/2}\sqrt{\pi}\;\Gamma(m+1)}
$$
and
$$
B_m(z) = \frac{\Gamma(m+\frac32)}{\Gamma(m+1)}\;
\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{(z-1)^{m-k}\Gamma(k)}{z^{m+1-k}\Gamma(k+\frac12)}
$$

---

For example,  $$
A_{10}(z) = {\frac {969969\, \left( z-1 \right) ^{10}}{262144\,{z}^{21/2}}},
\\
B_{10}(z) = \frac{1}{{3932160\,{z}^{10}}}\; \big(68025825\,{z}^{9}-382331775\,{z}^{8}+1168982220{z}^{7}-2255541300\,{z}^{6}+2918514950{z}^{5}-2585198330{z}^{4}+1554721740\,{z}^{3}-609140532{z}^{2}+140645505z-14549535\big)
$$

Comment: That pesky sum is unfortunately hiding just another similar 2F1, so this basically amounts to a transformation. I also keep going in circles with this, which isn't really helping. But thanks for the contribution!

Comment: But it’s a finite summation.

Comment: And something nice, @GEdgar, is you can write simple recurrence relations for $A_m(z)$ and $B_m(z)$. $A_m(z)/A_{m-1}(z) = \frac{m + 1/2}{m} \frac{z-1}{z}$ is very nice!

Comment: Hmmm, I'll give it another look, I was too frustrated last night x)

Comment: Yup, this actually works, my bad!